# Handling javascript links in a standalone web app

Tags: javascript, pinterest, iphone-standalone-web-app

I found this javascript to turn a mobile site into a standalone web app. It works great except for with the Pinterest Pin button, which I believe is a javascript link. I'm not versed in javascript so I would be greatly appreciative if someone could show me how to add to this code to either open the pinterest link in safari or allow the users to pin within the standalone app. Thanks.

Here's the code I'm using.

```
(function(a,b,c){
    if(c in b && b[c]){
        var d,e=a.location,
        f=/^(a|html)$/i;
        a.addEventListener("click", function(a){
            d=a.target;
            while(!f.test(d.nodeName)) d=d.parentNode;
            "href" in d && (chref=d.href).replace(e.href,"").indexOf("#") && (!/^[a-z\+\.\-]+:/i.test(chref) || chref.indexOf(e.protocol+"//"+e.host)===0) && (a.preventDefault(),e.href=d.href)
        },!1)
    }
})(document,window.navigator,"standalone");
```